# Copy name from From line in email in Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird, copy-paste

How do I copy the person's name in the From line of an email in Thunderbird?

Answer (score 0):

More Actions -> View Source, and then find the From line and copy it from there. (You can do this using `Ctrl+F From:`).